# Is it possible for motion to process an mjpg-streamer live feed and send alerts to a client viewing an NGINX webpage live? Is PubNub a solution?

Tags: web-server, webcam, c, motion, javascript

I already have a web server set up with NGINX showing a live webcam feed from the mjpg streamer as part of a laser tag game where the idea is for the user to be able to view a live camera stream by going to a local website.  However, at this stage I would like to add motion detection capabilities by using the motion package, as shown [here](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/webcam-and-video-wizardry) to process the mjpg live stream.

The reason I don't want to simply use motion is because it has more of a delay than mjpg-streamer.  When the user is viewing the live camera feed from a page on the local web server, I would like for the user to be notified if there is any motion detection (possibly through a JavaScript alert).  Motion allows for any command to be run through the command line if motion is detected.

Is there a shell command (maybe even to start a python script, etc.) which could communicate real-time (AJAX setup on the web server?) to the live HTML page showing the live camera feed running on the client device?

I would really appreciate it if you could answer my question and help me with this issue!  Thanks for taking the time to read the question!

**Update:**

Ok, so I've been doing some research, and I believe (but I am not completely sure) that a publish-subscribe API could work for my purposes.  I found PubNub to be a popular for real-time communication.  I have also found some people using it with the Raspberry Pi like [in this example](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-07-21-getting-started-raspberry-pi-2-pubnub-c-programming-language/) (I am comfortable with C programming so I would prefer to use it to work with PubNub).

Looking around their website, I found it is possible to also use PubNub with JavaScript as well, and I was curious to see if the two languages might be able to work together with PubNub.  Theoretically, I would call a C program which would publish a message to the javascript on my NGINX web server, subscribed to the same channel.  Finally, the JavaScript might respond with an alert. I *think* this would all happen without reloading the page.

I have not completely solved the problem yet, so I am curious to see if others would have any thoughts on how to implement this.

Comment: If there this question is off-topic, please tell me in case I need to ask elsewhere.  Thank you!

Comment: Here is where I found JavaScript to be supported with PubNub: [JavaScript API Reference for Realtime Apps | PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference)

Comment: It's not exactly off-topic but it is bordering on "too broad" and "unclear" -- not something I would answer personally anyway. I would suggest that AJAX has been superseded by websockets (which would be fairly simple to implement server-side in C and have client side support in js everywhere now); I think it should even be possible to do a bit of a redirect including the port so you could use a dedicated websocket based server for the feed (I'm not positive about that nor an nginx user, in which context I *think* it might be more easily accomplished by a peer connection on the server).

Comment: I think I might have solved the issue but I have yet to try it out.  I am going along with the PubNub update I provided earlier.  I found [here](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-30-create-realtime-raspberry-pi-security-camera-w-parse/) that folks over at PubNub used different technologies to detect the motion, but then they used python to notify JavaScript.  If I can do the same in C, I could notify the JavaScript application listening on the channel.  I might be getting somewhere here; now I have a little proof my update idea might work.  By the way, thanks @goldilocks for the feedback.

Comment: With that said, do you guys think there is anything I can do to improve the clarity of the question?

Comment: Yeah.  It reads like stream-of-consciousness.  Since we are *not* a discussion forum, brainstorming type proposals do not fly well.  You need to focus on something specific.  I think you essentially are, which is why I did not close the question to start with, but it is buried in (to be blunt) a lot of rambling.  Another turn-off are questions where someone has written 500-1000 words then adds: **Update:** with another bunch of paragraphs.  It just implies you are too lazy to re-write your question properly, and laziness from a questioner does not inspire others to devote time to them.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so unclear with my question; I really appreciate everyone who helps out on this site.  I was looking on how to ask a good question and it said to provide updates as you research more about the issue.  I was trying to provide as much context as possible as succinctly as possible (212 words without the update), and with my update I was hoping to help those answering the question by providing information about an API that _might_ work to solve the issue.  I did not want to change the question to ask about the API because it might not have been the best way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested earlier, PubNub turned out to be the perfect solution to this problem.

Basically, I used PubNub's Posix C API to connect to my client's web browser.  So, the motion daemon would execute the C program, which in turn would publish to the PubNub service.  The JavaScript would be subscribed to the same channel, and would pick up the message and play an alert on the web browser.

Links to the C and JavaScript publish/subscribe tutorials:

- Posix C Publish/Subscribe: [here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/posix-c/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe)
- JavaScript Publish/Subscribe: [here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe)

With these resources, connecting was actually fairly simple.  Just sign up for a PubNub account, create an 'app', and create a key to use for connecting the two devices.

However, the only hiccup I ran into was trying to use PubNub's new c-core library on GitHub; I could not install it on the raspberry pi.  I had to user their older C library which was used in the tutorial I provided in my question with my update.